# set windows environment variables using java

Tags: java, windows, environment-variables, cobol, microfocus

I have a Java app which makes a rest API call and returns a `String`. The string needs to be passed on to a Cobol app (Microfocus Cobol). Currently the java app do a sysout of the string to the console. What's the best approach to capture this value from console using micro focus cobol?

The cobol app is stand alone and invokes the java app to get the string data.
Need to identify a way for cobol to read in the value displayed on the output console.

Comment: "the best approach" is in the eye of the beholder.  What have you tried?

Comment: @cschneid - Currently the string is displayed to the console. Based on some articles I read, its not possible to write to env variables using Java(maybe I am wrong?). But I am not an expert as I never tried this approach before. So just looking for ideas from the experts here.

Comment: You should add more detail on what you are doing. Is Java code launching the Cobol app, or are you expecting an already running Cobol app to receive an environment variable change?

Comment: Also: you may want to just pass the value when starting a COBOL program under JVM (not sure as that info is missing: is the a "native/system" COBOL application or one of a COBOL runtime [wrapped] in Java?)

Comment: @DuncG - The cobol app is a standalone app. It will call the java app which internally makes  the api  call  and return the string printed onto the console. And the cobol needs to somehow access the string from the output console window.

Comment: @SimonSobisch - its a legacy app, so native/system cobol app.

Comment: Ah, you have native exe (cobrun.exe or friends) `CALL "SYSTEM" USING "java-app"` and want to pass data "upwards" from the java part, correct?
Then either use a pipe, for example via `OPEN java-proc` with `java-proc` being defined as `LINE SEQUENTIAL ASSING TO "<java-proc"`, or write it to a file, reading it that way.

You never pass environment variables "upwards", only "down".